# ITextSharp - How to know if a table will go to a next page?

Tags: itext

I am writing into a document multiple tables using ITextSharp.

How to know if a table will go to a next page, so then I could remove a certain cell?

P.S. I am using `table.KeepTogether = true;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ColumnText` in simulation mode to find out if elements fit a specific rectangle. See also [How to fit a String inside a rectangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526043/how-to-fit-a-string-inside-a-rectangle)

For instance:

```
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);
ct.SetSimpleColumn(36, 36, 559, 806);
ct.AddElement(table);
int status = ct.Go(true);
```

I used coordinates `(36, 36)` and `(559, 806)` because I assume that you have an A4 document with a margin of half an inch. If `ColumnText.HasMoreText(status)` is `true`, then the table object didn't fit the page. If that value is `false`, then the table fits the page and you can even use `ct.GetYLine()` method to find out the Y coordinate where the table ends.

Based on this information, you can add an altered table or the existing table to a `ColumnText` object, reset the simple column and use `Go(false)` (or `Go()`) to add the content for real.

See also:

- [iText - Strange column- / page changing behaviour with ColumnText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387642/itext-strange-column-page-changing-behaviour-with-columntext)
- [ColumnText and truncate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20257667/columntext-and-truncate-issue)
- [How to adjust the page height to the content height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186661/adjust-page-height-to-content-height)